# Java Heap not getting Garbage Collected after heavy process finished in Wildfly Server Group

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, wildfly, heap-memory

Process loads 1.5 Million record in memory.

Following is JVM Options for servergroup:

```
JVM Options
-d64 -Xms1024m -Xmx6044m -XX:ThreadStackSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewRatio=2
```

Process finished but heap not get empty and monitoring it for last 15 mins: (When process started it has only 200MB initially in used and 800MB in commited.
[image]

What is reason of no immediate garbage collection? How can garbage collection start after finishing process? How can I initiate it manually at least?

Comment: you want to un-commit that memory? if so you need either at least jdk-12 with `G1` or use `Shenandoah`

Comment: you mean just put -XX:+UseShenandoahGC  in wildfly vm arguments?

Comment: I mean you read and understand what you are doing, don't "just" put that argument in.

Comment: Why do you care?  Is the server still running?  Are there any issues?

Comment: When integration is executed again then OOM appears

Comment: We need more information - it's impossible to guess what your code does.